# Rank Values by Partition in SQL

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a new column that counts unique partitions of another column.

```
 ColA *NewCol
 ------------
 A    1
 A    1
 A    1
 B    2
 B    2
 C    3
 C    3
 C    3
```

I have tried using

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColA)
```

but each partition's count stays the same at 1.

How would I go about getting results for *NewCol?

Comment: Which dbms?????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for just the `order by`

```
select dense_rank(*) over (order by cola)
```

The `partition by` causes the value to be `1` for all `cola`, because only one value is considered in each partition.